# React Functional components Form handling with object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im trying to create a form with functional components in React. I have a state which contains an object

```
const [event, setEvent] = useState(props.location.event);
{
    "id": 1,
    "limit": 2000,
    "price": 10,
    "accessLvl": 0,
    "details": "Event that contains all the fields",
    "duration": 24,
    "eventType": 1,
    "eventLocation": "asdasd",
    "creator": 1,
    "startDate": "2020-06-01T12:00:00",
    "title": "Testing update",
    "imageUrl": "d0659c5e-7ca1-4b02-b148-6221d6e7d7a8"
}
```

It is a edit form so i have the input values set to these variables. With class component i could do it easily but with functional component when i try to change one variable for example title and the object is only going to contain the title which is not the behavior that i want.

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" value={props.event.title} onChange={e => props.onTodoChange(e.target.value, "title")} id="EventTitle" />

  function onTodoChange(value, key) {
    setEvent({[key] : value})
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will this work?

```
function onTodoChange(value, key) {
  setEvent(ev => ({
    ...ev,
    [key] : value,
  }))
}
```

The function `setEvent` can take a function with one argument that is the previous `event`. The `...ev` copies all of `ev`'s properties into the new object, then you overwrite the needed property with `[key] : value`.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:

```js
setState(prevState => { // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

Another option is useReducer, which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.

Doc [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Answer (score 1):

```
    setEvent({...event, [name of varible]: value})
ex: setEvent({...event, title:'Hi'})
```

This is the way to update object using hooks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * 
 *   USAGE: 
 *  1. const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
 *   
 *  2. const setsProperty = formObjectMutator(setProfile, () => validationErrors && setValidationErrors(null));
 *   
 *  3. <input type="text" onChange={setsProperty('firstName')} />
 * 
 * @param  {function}  clearMessagesFn  Clears validation messages once the user starts typing (optional).
 * @param   {function} setValueFn       The function that is used to modify the state object
 * @returns {function} A fuction that takes a propertry name and returns a function that handles change events for that property
 */
export  const formObjectMutator = (mutateStateFn, clearMessagesFn) => property => event => {
        // This line is necessary, do not access the event object from the function passed to the 
        // mutator function or you will cause a bug.
        const newValue = event.target.value;

        mutateStateFn(prevState => { return { ...prevState, [property]: newValue} } );

        if(clearMessagesFn)
            clearMessagesFn();
}
```